# Pushing values and keys to an multidimensional array from the database inside a foreach loop without repetitions

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, foreach, push

I'm trying to combine two tables from a database, and based on my first one, I want to retrieve some value from the other one, and add them to an array.

Here's my problem:

My first database looks like that:

```
FIRST TABLE:
id, credit_type, association_name, address, city, province, postal_code, country, cycle_type, cycle_begin, cycle_months
```

My second database instead looks like that:

```
SECOND TABLE:
id, association_id, designation_name
```

The id in my first table matches the association_id in my second table so I don't need an INNER JOIN.

My approach is the following:

```
<?php

public function my_function()
{

    $sql = ee()->db->select('*')->from('first_table')->get();

    $data['database'] = [];

    if ($sql->num_rows() > 0)
    {
        foreach($sql->result_array() as $row)
        {   
            $id[] = $row['id'];
            $data['database'][] = $row;
        }

    }

    foreach ($data['database'] as $key => $value) {

        $association_query = ee()->db->query("SELECT * FROM second_table WHERE id = $id");
        foreach($association_query->result_array() as $row_two)
        {
            if ($association_query->num_rows() > 0)
            {
                $data['database'][$key]['associations'][] = $row_two['designation_name'];
            }
        }
    }

    return ee()->load->view('index', $data, true);
}
?>
```

The sintax `ee()->db->select('*')` is a prepared statment from expression engine and it's equal to SELECT * FROM first_table (sanitaized).

So as you can see, I try to pass the value `$id`, which is an array, to my query. The thing is that as soon as I push the value like that `$id[] = $row['id']` I create a nice array, but when I loop through my foreach loop, it multiplies my array in many other arrays so I'm not able to run my query, even if I'm technically in a foreach loop.

Plus, as soon as I try to push the result of my query in my array, let's say changing the id in a static id for instance id=3, I obtain a really weird result, like so many arrays repeated with 1 value, 2 value, 3 value and so on, when I'd like to push my key 'association' only where it is presented in the other table.

Comment: What is the result you want to have? It's not clear to me what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: There are several things wrong with this code.  First off, interpolating `$id[]` will just print `Array` in your string and your query will never be completed.  Secondly checking for `->num_rows()` should be the first check before you call `->result_array()`.  Third, your best bet is to fetch ALL the rows into a variable and just assign the `$data['database'][$key]['association'] = $allRows` instead of going through a foreach loop.

Comment: I'd like to create an array in which I would push some values from one table of the database: $data['database'][] = $row; and I would like to add a field (a key), which is another array inside the same array like that: $data['database'][$key]['associations'][] = $row_two['designation_name'];

Comment: something like:

$data['database'] = array() -> value:

id = 1,
credit_type = 2,
association_name = something,
address, city = someadress,
and so on until the last value which could be something like
association = another_array();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you won't do it on SQL, at least don't execute the second query so many times.

```
<?php

public function my_function()
{
    $assocs = array();
    $data = array('database' => array());

    $association_query = ee()->db->query("SELECT * FROM second_table");
    if ($association_query->num_rows() > 0) {
        foreach($association_query->result_array() as $row) {
            $assocs[$row['association_id'][] = $row['designation_name'];
        }
    }

    $sql = ee()->db->select('*')->from('first_table')->get();    
    if ($sql->num_rows() > 0)   {
        foreach($sql->result_array() as $row) {   
            $id_check = $row['id'];
            if (isset($assocs[$id_check])) {     
                $row ['associations'] = $assocs[$id_check] ;
            }
            $data['database'][] = $row;
        }

    }


    return ee()->load->view('index', $data, true);
}
?>
```

Regards

Comment: Great solution! 

I'm actually trying to echo my variable but I receive an advice:

<tr>
                <th>Hidden Value</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <th><?php echo $item["associations"]; ?></th>  
            </tr>

This will produce -> Array to string conversion, but I don't quite understand why, since the echo is within a foreach loop.. Do you know why?

Comment: $item["associations"] is an array containing all the "designation_name" for that "association_id" (in case should be more than one). You could use `echo implode(', ', $item['associations'])` to enumerate them